# How can I solve this referencing Problem in mongoose/Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I have route and model for User and then another for Loan. I'm trying to reference the user inside the Loan route but I get this error anytime I test on PostMan:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Micho\Documents\GBENGA\BE\src\routes\loans\index.js:38:47
```

Loan Model code is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const loanSchema = new Schema({
    customerName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    gender: {
        type: String
    },
    address: {
        city: String,
        state: String,
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number
    },
    loanTenure: {
        type: Number
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    loanStatus: {
        type: String,
        default: "created"
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
```

My route is this:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {

      let loan = await new Loan({...req.body});

      loan.save();

        await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, { $push: { loans: loan._id } })
        console.log(req.user)

      loan = await Loan.findById(loan._id).populate("user");
      res.send(loan);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      res.status(500).send(error);
    }
  });
```

Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: I think this `req.user._id` has to be `req.body.user._id`, just print `req` and check what you're getting in, if needed use `JSON.parse()`. Also I don't think you need to use `await` at this step `let loan = await new Loan({...req.body});` rather you can have await at `loan.save()`;

Comment: @Olusanya, can you post your user model? You have `ref: 'User'`, it might actually need to be `ref: 'user'`, but you need to post your user model.